# Need Steps to Install multisite configuration using only drush. i.e multi-site install having different database

Tags: database, drush, multi-sites

I need a help to install multi-site setup using only Drush that have multiple/different databases.I have already installed a site using drush but when I do the same steps for install another site into the sites folder using drush it gives me an error to delete previous database. I want instead to install another site that having same code base but different database.

1. Install site in /var/www/html/abc
2. Install another in /var/www/abc/sites/xyz.com

Gives error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`drush site-install --db-url=mysql://USER:PASS@localhost/DATABASENAME --sites-subdir=sitename`

You may also need to add `--db-su` and `--db-su-pw` if necessary to provide the right credentials to create the database if the user specified by `USER:PASS` does not have permissions to do this.

See `drush help site-install` for other useful optional options you might want to specify, e.g. site name, admin account details and so on.